# Socket.io 0.9 and firefox 3.6 - error when close tab

Tags: socket.io, firefox3.6

My firefox 3.6 gets error when I close connected to socket.io server tab in browser:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIDOMJSWindow.setTimeout]"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: address.pl:PORT/socket.io/socket.io.js :: anonymous :: line 2057"  data: no]

Other browsers are fine, even IE8

Comment: In my country people still use it. And I'd like to make it work for them correctly.

Comment: Time to upgrade to a more recent version of Firefox, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem may be this bug:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=630386

As you can see, they have marked it as "RESOLVED WORKSFORME" because the bug is fixed in Firefox 4.0 as a side-effect of other work.

Which leaves you with a couple of realistic options:

- try to figure out a workaround (good luck!), or
- recommend that users of your product upgrade to a later version of Firefox.

Note that FF 3.6 has been "end-of-lifed", so the chances of getting a fix into the codebase for this version are asymptotic to zero.